# Building Subversion on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, python-3.x, build-process

I'm currently trying to build subversion 1.7.3 with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on Windows 7 SP1.
I'm not really experienced in building open source software myself, but it's not always easy to find a complete binary package where I can find the right modules for. Therefore I thought I try building it myself. Now I'm stuck at executing the gen-make.py and can't find any solutions on the web.

The error is, I get an invalid syntax error:

```
File "gen-make.py", line 271
    except getopt.GetoptError, e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't think it has to do with the dependencies I submitted, because the same error is shown when I open the gen-make.py in IDLE.
I'm not experienced with python or compiling open source software myself. So I'm stuck and can't figure out what's going wrong.

I'm using Python 3.2.2.

I'm calling python with the following line:

```
F:\Open Source\subversion-1.7.3>python gen-make.py -t vcproj --vsnet-version=2010 --with-berkeley-db=..\bdb --with-openssl=..\openssl-1.0.0g --with-httpd=..\httpd-2.4.1 --with-neon=..\neon --with-serf=..\serf --with-sqlite=..\sqlite --with-zlib=..\zlib
```

Has anyone some clues what I am missing here?

====
**Update:**
I've tried it with Python 2.7. And the syntax error is gone. But nothing is perfect. ;)
Now I'm facing another problem: It says it can't find apr, I've downloaded apr yet having trouble getting it to work. I'm tired now and I think I'll come back tomorrow, looking into it.
The exact error is as follows:

```
ERROR: '..\httpd-2.4.1\srclib\apr\include\apr_version.h' not found.
Use '--with-apr' option to configure APR location.
```

Greetings,
Skalli

Comment: That's true. I'll try to figure it out on my own first before opening a new question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's Python 2 syntax, run it with Python 2 instead.

Comment: Ok, I did it with 2.7. The syntax error is gone, now I have a different error, I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Skalli: You'll probably get more eyes on it if you post a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've never built Subversion on Windows. However, I know there's a major difference between Python 3.x syntax and Python 2.7.x syntax, and that one is not compatible with the other.

Were you told to use Python 3.x? Most people are still using Python 2.7.x, and I suspect that you need to use Python 2.7.x.